# compile log4cpp for visual studio 2005

Tags: c++, log4cpp

We have a legacy c++ project written by visual studio 2005. we want to replace it's internal logger with [log4cpp](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/). I downloaded version 1.1.3. But there is no ready-to-use solution for vs2005. So i created an empty win32 project:

***Configuration type: Static Library (.lib)***

And added by hand all `.cpp` and `.hh` files to it and compiled it.

It compiled with 5 errors at the end:
https://gist.github.com/LinArcX/c66dc8bd5afa1868e79feef841a3af23

It complains about some identifier that didn't find:

```
1>d:\mylog4cpp\src\dailyrollingfileappender.cpp(55) : error C3861: 'time': identifier not found
1>d:\mylog4cpp\src\dailyrollingfileappender.cpp(62) : error C3861: 'localtime_s': identifier not found
1>d:\mylog4cpp\src\dailyrollingfileappender.cpp(95) : error C3861: 'time': identifier not found
1>d:\mylog4cpp\src\dailyrollingfileappender.cpp(155) : error C3861: 'time': identifier not found
1>d:\mylog4cpp\src\dailyrollingfileappender.cpp(160) : error C3861: 'localtime_s': identifier not found
```

I've tried to add `time.h` to `dailyrollingfileappender.cpp`, but got another errors:
https://gist.github.com/LinArcX/1ab580bb4860eaddd374dcadd6b5211b

Comment: You need to link with `Ws2_32.lib` and possibly others. You should be able to search for all of those function names and find the library it belongs to.

Comment: define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE in one of your common headers, or build project.
And indeed link to ws2_32.lib.

You can force this with adding
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
to a source or header file