# Access violation writing location when using log4cpp

Tags: c++, log4cpp

I [successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68782821/) compiled log4cpp for Visual Studio 2005 (Debug-mode).

And created a [test](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/#simpleexample) console application. It links and compiled successfully.

But when I start it in debug-mode, it throws an error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x772febc3 in Log4CppClient.exe: 0xC0000005:
> Access violation writing location 0x00000014.

This is the content of the output window in Visual Studio:

```
'Log4CppClient.exe': Loaded 'D:\MyLog4Cpp\Debug\Log4CppClient.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Log4CppClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Log4CppClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Log4CppClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', No symbols loaded.
'Log4CppClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.42_none_ef74ff32550b5bf0\msvcp80d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Log4CppClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.42_none_ef74ff32550b5bf0\msvcr80d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Log4CppClient.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', No symbols loaded.
First-chance exception at 0x772febc3 in Log4CppClient.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014. Unhandled exception at 0x772febc3 in Log4CppClient.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014.
```

Edit: Here is the project:
https://github.com/LinArcX/MyLog4Cpp

Comment: Looks like a null pointer dereference.

Comment: Break into the debugger after the exception to see what variable is a null pointer.

Comment: `'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'` may be your bug. I think it should end in d before the dll. Are you sure you linked to the debug version of `log4cpp`?

Comment: Please 1) read [ask], then 2) post your code

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, i linked to debug version of `log4cpp`.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica 2) Repository added.

Answer (score 0):

Access Violation means that you are trying to access a memory address that you don't have permission to access.

Here, in your case, you are trying to write to the address 0x00000014, but you do not have permission/priviledges to do so.

Please share your code for more details.

(Maybe you are using a pointer without assigning it an address first?)

Comment: Thanks for explanations. I edited the post and added the repository of my code.